# Android get JSON array without a name

Tags: android

I got the following JSON data from my API:

[image]

Json array and alot of json objects in it.

How do I get a json array without a name?

This is what I tried:

```
//Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
 j = new JSONObject(response);
result = j.getJSONArray('');
 for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("tag", "NAME IS: " +json.getString("name"));
}
}
```

the `json` variable stores all the json data!

Comment: Try to replace the `' '` with `" "`, and if it doesn't work try with `""`

Comment: Doesn't work. If I'm changing my API and name my array, and type in there "myArray", it works.. without a name - it doesnt :S

Comment: Does your response begin with this array ?

Comment: I change my API to output `"myArray [...` because an empty one doesn't work with Android, or a way I don't know.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, is you no-name array the root of your Json response ? If so, just follow  USKMobility answer and it will work

Answer (score 3):

JSONArray has a constructor which takes a String source.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(yourJSONArrayAsString);
```

Then you can get each object using for loop.

```
JSONArray array;
    try {
        array = new JSONArray(yourJSONArrayAsString);

        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
            JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
            // get your data from jsonobject
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: But my response is a json object I guess.. I do `j = new JSONObject(response);`

Answer (score -1):

create JSONParser class which contains json parsing code.

Mention in Your MainActivity.java

JSONParser jsonparser=new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject=jsonparser.getJSONFromURL(URL);

Now Create separate JSONParser class

```
class JSONParser
{
   public static JSONObject jsonObject=null;
   public static String json=null;
   InputStream is=null;
   public JSONObject getJSONFromURL(String url)
{ 
    try
{
      HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);
      HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);
      HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
      is=entity.getContent();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
try
{
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
  StringBuilder sb=-new StringBuilder();
  String line=null;
  while((br.readLine())!=null)
  {
    sb.append(line+"\n");
  }
 json=sb.toString();
 is.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
 try
{
  jsonObject=new JSONObject(json.subString(json.indexOf("{"),json.lastinddexOf("}")+1));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
return jsonObject;
}
```

Now in MainActivity.java

```
try
{
JSONParser jsonparser=new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject=jsonparser.getJSONFromURL(URL);// URL is a String which contains url
Log.d("Response:",jsonObject.toString());
JSONArray jsonarray=new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("YourFirstJSONArrayName"));//YourJSONArray contains the response array
for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++)
 {
   JSONObject c=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
   // now get data from c object
 }
// Now getting data from Second Array
 JSONArray jsona=new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("YourSecondJSONArrayName"));
   for(int j=0;j<jsona.length();j++)
{
    JSONObject c=jsona.getJSONObject(j);
      // now get data from json data from second array
}
 }
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```